# What is the best way to code up a Month and Year drop down list for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an internal application that I needs to have a drop down list for two date type elements:  **Month** and **Year**.  These values are not in a database or other repository of information.

I know I could just setup a list with the values I need by adding them to a dictionary like object (I need to correlate the Month to the numerical representation, January => 01):

```
var months = new Dictionary<String,String>();
months.Add("01", "January");
...
```

The drop down list for the year will be a bit easier as I can just choose a starting year and iterate up to the current or current+1 year in a generic list.

Is there a better way to handle these data elements?  Something built in, or a good design pattern that I should be implementing?

Comment: Interesting question, I have had the same question once. +1

Comment: Do you need to localize this value?

Comment: Localization isn't a requirement, however if it already exists in a localized state, it wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use this to get a list of all the Month names and loop through it.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
```

You can use it like this...using the index of the Month as the value for your dropdown

```
var months = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++)
{
     ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(months[i], i.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to corrolate a month name with the numeric representation (i.e. January => 1)?

Comment: The array returned by CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames contains contains "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", and "" in order. You can use a for loop to get the index for each value.

Comment: Great answer!  I love StackOverflog -- I truly learn something new at least twice a day.  I've added my contribution in homage to @Jesse Brown's answer in another answer.

Comment: The only issue I see with this: Is the order of the returned array of Month Names going to remain the same (if the order gets messed up, it would be possible for January to all of a sudden be assigned the number 5).  That is my only concern with this method.

Comment: be sure to check out the other properties on DateTimeFormat - such as AbbreviatedMonthNames. Don't just do substring(0,3) !!

Comment: For localized month names, use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.

Comment: months.DataSource = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
            months.DataBind();

and use like months.SelectedIndex + 1

Answer (score 5):

Extending @Jesse Brown's answer...

With a **using System.Globalization** directive, I have the following code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
{
    cboMonth.Items.Add
    (
       (x+1).ToString("00") 
       + " " 
       + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.GetValue(x)
     );
}
```

This produces a dropdown list that looks like:

01 January
02 February
03 March
...
12 December

A further refinement might be to make the displayed month the current month by adding:

```
cboMonth.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00") 
   + " " 
   + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.GetValue(DateTime.Now.Month);
```

After the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, which is very similar to @jesse-brown's solution (the accepted answer)

VB.NET:

In a global functions class:

```
Public Shared Function GetMonthList() As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim months As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    For m As Int32 = 1 To 12
        months.Add(String.Format("{0:0#}", m), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(m))
    Next

    Return months
End Function
```

On the ASPX page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ddMonth.DataSource = GlobalFunctions.GetMonthList()
    ddMonth.DataValueField = "Key"
    ddMonth.DataTextField = "Value"
    ddMonth.DataBind()

End Sub
```

This implementation is in VB.NET because that happens to be what this webapp is using (legacy), however thank you very much for the examples in C# (my preferred language), I'm posting the VB.NET here to help the VB.NET community as well.

Answer (score 3):

Below code is for load month dropdown as **Select**

```
    private void LoadMonth()
    {
        ddlmonth.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", 0.ToString()));
        var months = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < months.Length-1; i++)
        {
            ddlmonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(months[i], (i+1).ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation about your code. This way your answer will be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET MVC this is what I'm doing.

Note [I prefer to use a codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108320/code-behind-in-asp-net-mvc/527189#527189) for things like this - its still part of the view and there's nothing wrong with the view constructing a SelectList.

**PaymentControl.ascx**

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("ExpirationMonth", ExpirationMonthDropdown)%> / 
 <%= Html.DropDownList("ExpirationYear", ExpirationYearDropdown)%>
```

**PaymentControl.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class PaymentControl : ViewUserControl<CheckoutModel>
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationMonthDropdown
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x =>

                    new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[x - 1] + " (" + x + ")",
                        Value = x.ToString(),
                        Selected = (x == Model.ExpirationMonth)
                    });
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationYearDropdown
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year, 20).Select(x =>

                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = x.ToString(),
                    Value = x.ToString(),
                    Selected = (x == Model.ExpirationYear)
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once I use this `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationMonthDropdown
        {` inside my model class I'm getting following error `The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void bind_month()
    {
        var months = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;

        ddl_month.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

        for (int i = 0; i < months.Length-1; i++)
        {
            ddl_month.Items.Add(new ListItem(months[i],(i+1).ToString()));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Somebody has asked that they wanted a numeric representation of the months. Here's my codebehind:

```
// DOB MONTHS
dob_month1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "")); 
var months = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
for (int i = 1; i < months.Length; i++)
{
    dob_month1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
}
```

It's basically the same as the answer code with minor adjustments.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

/*Try this code to bind all month in dropdown list without using database*/

```
 public void GetMonthList(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        DateTime month = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2000");
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            DateTime NextMont = month.AddMonths(i);
            ListItem list = new ListItem();
            list.Text = NextMont.ToString("MMMM");
            list.Value = NextMont.Month.ToString();
            ddl.Items.Add(list);
        }
        //ddl.Items.Insert(0, "Select Month");
        ddl.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this...
 Ref Here:

http://allinworld99.blogspot.com/2015/01/bind-monthsyear-dropdownlist-c-aspnet.html

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    drpBMonth.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()))};
```

Comment: Hi there, both link-only answers and code-only answers are discouraged here. Can you edit your answer to explain how this solves the OP's problem?