# ASP.NET Get future 6 months

Tags: asp.net, datetime

So what I am looking to do is to get future six months in a dropdown box and I was trying something like

```
        public List<String> GetTrainingDates()
    {
        var monthList = new List<String>();
        var currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
        for(var i = currentMonth; i <= currentMonth + 6; i++)
        {
            monthList.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i));
        }
        return monthList;
    }
```

But ofcourse this goes greater than 12, so would have to restart at 12 and then start from 1 again.

Just wondering if anybody has a good idea how to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812330/what-is-the-best-way-to-code-up-a-month-and-year-drop-down-list-for-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`%` modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

```
monthList.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(
               ((i - 1) % 12) + 1));
```

Comment: @freefaller - adjusted for `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public List<String> GetTrainingDates()
        {
            var monthList = new List<String>();
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now();
            for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {              
                monthList.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(currentDate.AddMonths(i).Month));
            }
            return monthList;
        }
```

Comment: This will not get the _next_ 6 months. Just January to June.

Comment: @Oded Please explain? I don't agree.

Comment: Apologies - missed the use of `DateTime.Now.AddMonths`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.AddMonths` function of the `DateTime` class...

```
public List<String> GetTrainingDates()
{
    var monthList = new List<String>();
    var month;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
       month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).Month;
       monthList.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month));
    }
    return monthList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use `LINQ` expression with `Range`.....

```
 List<string> listMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).ToList()
                             .Select(i => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).Month))
                             .ToList();
```