# Month and Year drop down list for ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to populate Month and Year in asp.net mvc project's cshtml view page

this is the  view page code

```
@model IEnumerable<project.Models.ProductStatistics>

@{

 }

@Html.DropDownList("ExpirationMonth", ExpirationMonthDropdown)
@Html.DropDownList("ExpirationYear", ExpirationYearDropdown)
```

this is the model

```
public class ProductStatistics
{

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationMonthDropdown
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x =>

                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[x - 1] + " (" + x + ")",
                    Value = x.ToString(),
                    Selected = (x == Model.ExpirationMonth)
                });
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationYearDropdown
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year, 20).Select(x =>

            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.ToString(),
                Value = x.ToString(),
                Selected = (x == Model.ExpirationYear)
            });
        }
    }

}
```

but here I'm getting following error in Model Class

> The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context

also getting this error in view page

> The name 'ExpirationMonthDropdown' does not exist in the current context

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. The first error is obvious: you're accessing `Model` in your `ProductStatistics` methods, which does not exist there. `Model` only exists as a member variable in views. The second error is because your view's model is `IEnumerable<albaraka.Models.ProductStatistics>`, so even if you were  to use `Model.ExpirationMonthDropdown`, it won't work, because enumerable != 1. Please show some more relevant code.

Comment: @CodeCaster do I need to move `ExpirationMonthDropdown` and `ExpirationYearDropdown` methods to controller method

Comment: No, you need to show more code, for example where `ExpirationMonth` and `ExpirationYear` are defined.

Comment: The first error is thrown by your line `Selected = (x == Model.ExpirationMonth)` (x2) becuse your model does not contain a property name `Model`. But since you binding to a property name `ExpirationMonth`, then its ignored anyway so just delete it.

Comment: The second error is because you have not defined `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties in the view named `ExpirationMonthDropdown` and `ExpirationYearDropdown` - but you use of `@model IEnumerable<project.Models.ProductStatistics>` in the view makes no sense so impossible to understand what you think your trying to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke simply i want to populate two dropdowns for month and year , I just followed [4th answer of this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812330/what-is-the-best-way-to-code-up-a-month-and-year-drop-down-list-for-asp-net)

Comment: Not sure why that answer got any up votes - it simply does not work. shu's answer should put you on the right track (so long as you change the model to `@model ProductStatistics` (not `IEnumerable<ProductStatistics>`). But if your model is a collection, then you need to use a loop to iterate through each item in the collection.

Comment: And have you abandoned your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601002/model-property-multiselectlist-values-store-in-javascipt)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no combination between this question and previous one

Comment: Its just that you never added the script and the controller method in that question in order to add an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your model with following code

```
public class ProductStatistics
{

   [Display(Name = "Product ID")]
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class ProductStatisticsList
{
    public List<ProductStatistics> Products
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int SelectedMonth
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int SelectedYear
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In the action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Months = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x =>
      new SelectListItem()
              {
                  Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[x - 1] + " (" + x + ")",
                  Value = x.ToString()
              }), "Value", "Text");



        ViewBag.Years = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year, 20).Select(x =>

           new SelectListItem()
           {
             Text = x.ToString(),
             Value = x.ToString()
           }), "Value", "Text");

      ProductStatisticsList p = new ProductStatisticsList();
     // p.Products = new List<ProductStatistics>();
      //p.Products.Add(new ProductStatistics { Product_ID = "Product_ID", ProductName = "ProductName" });
      p.Products = (from productstatistics in db.ProductStatistics

                    select new ProductStatistics
                    {
                        Product_ID = productstatistics.Product_ID,
                        ProductName = productstatistics.ProductName,

                    }).ToList();



        p.SelectedMonth = 3;
        return View(p);
 }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductStatisticsList model)
    {
        //do the stuff
    }
```

in your view

```
@model project_name.Models.ProductStatisticsList

@{

 }

  @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formIndex" }))
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMonth, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Months, "Month") 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedYear, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Years, "Year") 

    <table class="table">
        @if (Model.Products != null && Model.Products.Count > 0)
        {

            <tr>
                 <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.Products[0].Product_ID) @*This approch is wrong , should read from resource file*@
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.Products[0].ProductName) @*This approch is wrong , should read from resource file*@
                </th>               
           </tr>

            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Product_ID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Product_ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].ProductName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].ProductName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: then I'm getting following error `'IEnumerable<ProductStatistics>' does not contain a definition for 'ExpirationMonthDropdown' and no extension method 'ExpirationMonthDropdown' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<ProductStatistics>'`

Comment: @kez your model should be `ProductStatistics` not `'IEnumerable<ProductStatistics` .check out for model in my answer

Comment: pardon me to mention this in this model I have table also , to post as a simple question just left code snippet like this , once I made to `@model project.Models.ProductStatistics` getting following error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'project.Models.ProductStatistics' because 'project.Models.ProductStatistics' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: Ok in that case we need to fill the combo box using `ajax` or `viewbag`

Comment: I cannot understand you said , can I have an example

Comment: can you please post your `action` method

Comment: @kez, If you model is a collection, then it needs to be `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].ExpirationMonth, Model[i].ExpirationMonthDropdown, "Months") }` and it needs to be `@model IList<ProductStatistics>` (not `IEnumerable`). But if that is the case, you need to show more code

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes are absolutely correct, if the model is a collection.

Comment: @shu this is the whole [code segments](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/nr4aM)

Comment: @shu I need to get these selected month and value to post action , is that possible to do in your approch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104625/discussion-between-shu-and-kez).

Comment: Hi @shu in your first method to retrieve month, once I select value and click submit , then I check model values , I can see value for month property getting as 1 to 12 not as January to December , How can I get the string value , not the integer value ?

Comment: @kez in `ViewBag.Months` make the `Value` same as `Text` and make the `SelectedMonth property as string`