# Datepicker with only Years

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to implement an input datepicker in my asp.net-mvc project that display only years to create/edit new values of my model. I want the day and the month to be always the same (31/12/year) and allow the user to select only the year. Something like this:

[image]

In my model I have this datetime field:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime MyDate{ get; set; }
```

I tried "{0:yyyy-31-12}" but that don't work.

And this is the  Create view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is my result:

[image]

I need that picker to display only years (also in edit view) and retain fixed the day and the month (12/31). Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO create a `<select` with only years, and display "31/12" next to it, then bind only year to your model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to drop down the list of years, not datetimepicker.
you can see this solution
[Month and Year drop down list for ASP.NET mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623579/month-and-year-drop-down-list-for-asp-net-mvc/35624215).

And you can use [select2 plugin](https://select2.org/dropdown), it will help the users to search in dropdownlist

Comment: Hi. Maybe I need a list. But that list must display the years "automatically" like a datepicker. That is, show all the years without doing myself from code. Display all the years like a datepicker.

Comment: I did not see that before, I advice you do not lose your time in this and you can use drop down side label 31/12/ [year]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap-datepicker, try below format.

```
minViewMode
```

You can look at the document from here:
[bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#minviewmode)

Comment: Hi. I tried to use boostrap: https://qawithexperts.com/article/bootstrap/select-only-year-in-bootstrap-datepicker/323 but it didn't work. It display an input, but when I select the input, nothing appear. Maybe is because the sample is not complete. I would like some example like that url but complete. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Keras-JOB I tried now and that sample is working. Please make sure you added JQuery, bootstrap, and bootstrap-datepicker packages or cdns and the stylesheet links

Comment: I copy-paste all the code and it didn't work. Is because what you're saying: "JQuery, bootstrap, and bootstrap-datepicker packages or cdns and the stylesheet links". What I have to do? Install from nuget? Or just copy some css styles in my site.css?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @M Arif Sarıkaya.

I found why it don't work.
It's because of the _layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nombre de la aplicación", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acerca de", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacto", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This part was causing the error:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

If I delete it, shows the datepicker. But I don't know why and also if that will cause me other errors in the rest of views. Is there a way to combine them safely?